# Getting "fatal: Can't access remote" with Bitbucket and FTP server

Tags: ftp, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to automate Bitbucket commits with a FTP server, so whenever I commit on the repo it will build and upload it into the FTP server.

NOTE: I am doing this with my Bitbucket premium account and I can easily access and insert that server and its directories from Filezila.

My .yml file:

image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Production
        deployment: Production
        script:
         # - pipe: atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.3.6
                - apt-get update
                - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
                - git ftp init--user "$FTP_USERNAME" --passwd "$PASSWORD" ftp://$SEVER_ADDRESS/temp --all
```

Why I am getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvau0.png)?

> fatal: Can't access remote 'ftp://FTP_USERNAME:***@52.xxx.xx.xx', exiting...

Comment: Did you find a fix?